# How wise was Solomon regarding his accumulations of horses, wives, and gold?

Tags: deuteronomy, 1-kings

Moses on his dying day warned future kings in

> Deuteronomy 17:16 But the king must not acquire many **horses** for himself or send the people back to Egypt to acquire more horses, for the LORD has said, ‘You are never to go back that way again.’ 17He must not take many **wives** for himself, lest his heart go astray. He must not accumulate for himself large amounts of silver and **gold**.

God blessed Solomon with wisdom in

> 1 Kings 4:30
> Solomon's wisdom was greater than the wisdom of all the people of the East, and greater than all the wisdom of Egypt.

Despite Solomon's wisdom and knowledge, he didn't heed Moses' warnings

> 1 Kings 4:26
> Solomon had four thousand stalls for chariot horses, and twelve thousand **horses**.

> 1 Kings 11:3
> He had seven hundred **wives** of royal birth and three hundred concubines, and his wives led him astray.

> 1 Kings 10:21 All King Solomon’s goblets were **gold**, and all the household articles in the Palace of the Forest of Lebanon were pure gold. Nothing was made of silver, because silver was considered of little value in Solomon’s days.

By hindsight, Moses seemed to have written Deuteronomy 17:16-17 with Solomon particularly in mind.
What happened to Solomon's wisdom? What are the lessons for us?

Comment: The entire kingdom prospered, as opposed to only its king (presumably at the expense of others, as Deuteronomy seems to suggest), and this was achieved through wisdom (commerce and diplomacy), rather than brute force or military action (as with David and Saul before him).

Comment: See also [Deuteronomist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deuteronomist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Wisdom is applied knowledge.***  Solomon had plenty head knowledge but later in his life he disregarded the clear instructions that God had given to anyone who would be king.  Solomon started out well, but over time he failed to apply the counsel of Scripture and went his own, selfish way.  He knew what was right in God’s eyes, but he broke God’s laws in spite of being granted wisdom.  He was without excuse.

The reason why Solomon failed to apply his knowledge and wisdom concerning the acquisition of horses, women and wealth is found in 1 Kings 11:9:

> “The Lord became angry with Solomon because his heart had turned away from the Lord, the God of Israel, who had appeared to him twice.”

In this regard, Solomon was unlike his father David.  It is worth noting that Solomon strayed from God’s ways when he was older.  Solomon came to disregard the wisdom he had been given.

The lessons for us are clear.  If we are to please God we must study His word and apply it to our lives.  The acquisition of head knowledge is, of itself, meaningless.  We must apply it.  That means obeying God and following His instructions.

If we turn away from God, and if we become complacent, lukewarm and self-centred, we risk God’s displeasure and punishment.  The knowledge or wisdom that can be discovered in God’s Word has to result in a life transformed – a heart transplant, if you like.  To avoid the fate of Solomon we need to humble ourselves and place our faith and trust in God’s promises.  We have to be obedient.

Answer (score 2):

> **1 Kings 3:11-13** And the Lord said to Solomon: **Because thou hast** asked this thing, and hast not asked for thyself long life or riches, nor the lives of thy enemies, but hast **asked for thyself wisdom** to discern judgment, 12 **Behold I have** done for thee according to thy words, and have **given thee** a wise and understanding heart, insomuch that there hath been no one like thee before thee, nor shall arise after thee. 13 Yea and **the things also which thou didst not ask,** I have given thee: to wit riches and glory, as that no one hath been like thee among the kings in all days heretofore.

Moses only forbids a king seeking riches for riches sake; God granted Solomon riches because he didn't seek such things.

Besides this, being wise does not mean that one cannot sin — and all sin is foolish by nature; sin, in fact, is precisely the going against what one knows to be true.